# How i am getting long keep on in the setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

How this code works? any one help me to understand ?

```
var myArray = ['one','two','three'];

var logAll = function (){
    var long = myArray.length;
    for(i=0;i< long;i++){
        console.log(myArray[i]);
    }
    setTimeout(logAll,50);
}
logAll();
```

According to me, the myArray length is just 3, so, my log has to give me the result as 0,1,2. thats ok. out of my for loop i introduced a setTimeout for logAll function, but how that logAll function keep on calling the for loop instead of 3 times, to ever..? any one help me to understand this?

if so, why this is calling only one time ?

```
var myArray = ['one','two','three'];

    var logAll = function (){
        var long = myArray.length;
        for(i=0;i< long;i++){
            console.log(myArray[i]);
        }

    }
    setTimeout(logAll,50);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep calling `setTimeout` at the end of `logAll`, so it keeps calling `logAll` every 50ms.

Comment: @3gwebtrain I'm confused. Why does it only run once in the second code? Because it's called once at the end of the `setTimeout`, and never called again. A `setTimeout` times out, calls the method given to it, and that's it.

Comment: In the first function, i am not kept the "setTimeout(logAll,50);", inside of the loop, that why i am confused. my function called only one time, as well it's calling the inner function one time.. then how the inner function calling keep on?

Comment: @3gwebtrain It *doesn't* "keep going on"--at the end of the loop, you call `setTimeout` again. `logAll` returns, then when 50ms is up, it gets called *again*. If you put a `console.log("logAll");` at the beginning of the `logAll` function you'll see that it's called repeatedly.

Comment: yes, i am clear now... i am maaaad, sorry to waste you time. thanks for your spared time for me... good. you are helpyyyyyyyyyy!

Comment: @3gwebtrain Everything's obvious once we understand it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This function (logAll), is called once at start. Then it gets all keys/values from the array, and after 50 ms it repeats the process, which makes no sense to do it, but is usable if you want to check variable changes

> if so, why this is calling only one time ?

Because function is called only once and never again. `setTimeout()` only creates only one function call.

Comment: In case if i placed the setTimeout(logAll,50); inside of a function, then it will keep on calling? - is it correct?

Comment: yeah. Between as soon as question is called, setTimeout executes again, which executes the function again ... and so on. It's called recursion

Comment: @Martin Technically, not recursion, since the method returns before it's called again.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ Yeah I know, but that's *kind of* recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The setTimeout line means, wait 50ms, then call logAll. Because it's in logAll, it will run itself causing an infinite loop.

I'm not sure on the purpose of the setTimeout line, so I'd delete it!

Comment: Why would you delete it? Some infinite loops are also useful

Comment: Well, in this case I'm assuming it's not the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `logAll` ever 50 milliseconds so it is running through the for loop every 50 milliseconds. So it looks as though you are in a never ending loop, but infact you are just starting the loop constantly and your `console.log` will not look like it is logging in the correct order. e.g. before one loop has fully finished, another one has already started.

Answer (score 1):

By adding `setTimeout(logAll,50);`, you created an infinite loop.

If you want to log only the **new** content of the array, you either have to preserve `i` (so that you start with `i=3` in the next round) or you must clear the array.

The latter is probably better because that avoids a memory leak (the array would grow until it takes all memory).

To clear the array, set the `length` to `0`: `myArray.length = 0;`.

**[EDIT]** In the second example, `logAll` is called once because `setTimeout()` doesn't repeat; if you want a function to be called repeatedly, you must call `setTimeout()` again after executing the function.

[See the documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).